# Prometheus Query to Alert if the Metrics reporting same data for more than 15minutes

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We are running Confluent for Kunbernetes in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and via JMX metrics we are scrapping the metrics to Prometheus

After metrics are scrapped and we have added the custom rules for our Kafka environments and sending an alert.

As per our requirement we are running Oracle CDC Connector and for tracking the CDC lag we are uisng the below metrics query and it will return the lag in milliseconds (2553)

```
kafka_connect_oracle_cdc_source_task_metrics_number{connector='cars-cdc-incremental-load-task-v7',name='streaming-lag-from-source-in-milliseconds'}
```

There is case sometimes CDC connectors will go in to hanged mode and it will keep on reporting the same metrics for more than 1 to 4 hrs, in this case we need to alert.

Example

```
10:15 AM--> 2553 ms
10:20 AM--> 2553 ms
10:25 AM--> 2553 ms
10:30 AM--> 2553 ms
10:35 AM--> 2553 ms
10:40 AM--> 2553 ms
...
..
11:40 AM --> 2553 ms
```

If its reporting the same metrics for more than 15minutes we need to identify proactively and restart the connector to avoid the cdc lag

As per the CDC lag it should report the different lag metric data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Prometheus **[changes()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes)**:

```
changes(
  kafka_connect_oracle_cdc_source_task_metrics_number{
    connector='cars-cdc-incremental-load-task-v7',
    name='streaming-lag-from-source-in-milliseconds'
  }[15m]
)
```

The query returns the number of changes for the metric within `15min`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to check if value of the metric stayed the same over period of time, while also receiving value of the metric, is to compare results of `max_over_time` and `min_over_time`. If they are the same - value didn't change.

```
max_over_time(kafka_connect_oracle_cdc_source_task_metrics_number[15m]) == min_over_time(kafka_connect_oracle_cdc_source_task_metrics_number[15m])
```

Please notice, this expression will ignore periods of metric absence, and thus might result in false triggers near scrapping starts and ends for exporter. Mainly this shouldn't be an issue, but you might work around those situations by adding `for: 5m` for starts, and adding inhibition by alert for service down for ends.

Demo of similar expression [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=node_cpu_seconds_total&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=max_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B15m%5D)%20%3D%3D%20min_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B15m%5D)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h).