# Promql for alerting if the network bytes out traffic remains constant over a certain period of time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to create an expression for alerting in promql to check if the total network bytes sent out from AWS elasticache instance has remained constant or in a straight line over a period of time. For instance in the below graph, the issue was noticed at the time frame when the line remained fairly constant or without any spikes

[image: network bytes out graph]

Can someone please suggest me how I can proceed with this and what is the expression I should be using here to achieve my use case?

Comment: It depends on what means "remained fairly constant" exactly. For exactly constant values there a couple suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77414003), but you probably will need to use subquery syntax `[15m : ]`. Probably my answer in the linked question can be modified to allow some margin of error, but it requires more details for proper answer.

Comment: And it will benefit anybody who tries to help you, if you'll share your current query.